# Picklist field values extracting to CSV format

Tags: visualforce

```
public class getSpecialitiesForSelection {

    public List<SelectOption> sOptions {get;set;}
    public List<String> myString1 {get;set;}
    public List<String> myString2 {get;set;}
    String fieldname;
    String objectname;

    public getSpecialitiesForSelection(){
        sOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        myString1 = new List<String>();
        myString2 = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Specialty_1_vod__c;
        system.debug('Printing specialty values' + f);
        objectname ='Accounts';
        fieldname ='Specialty_1_vod__c';
        myString1.add(objectname);
        myString1.add(fieldname);
        for(Schema.PickListEntry p : f.getPicklistValues()){
            sOptions.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getLabel()));
        }


        Schema.DescribeFieldResult f1 = Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Specialty_2_vod__c;
        objectname ='Accounts';
        fieldname = 'Specialty_2_vod__c';
        myString1.add(objectname);
        myString1.add(fieldname);
        for(Schema.PickListEntry p1 : f1.getPicklistValues()){
            sOptions.add(new SelectOption(p1.getValue(), p1.getLabel()));
        }

    }
}
```

**Update**

Above i modified the class and adding
VF Page use - here teh problem is list is extracting twice, method is getting call two time, please let me know if something is wrong in below VF page

```
<apex:page controller="getSpecialitiesForSelection" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#Export.csv" language="en-US" >
"Object Name", "Field Name", "Picklist Value"
    <apex:repeat value="{!myString1}" var="a1" >
"{!a1}" 
        <apex:repeat value="{!myString2}" var="a2">
"", "{!a1}" 
            <apex:repeat value="{!sOptions}" var="a"> 
, , {!a.value}, {!a.label}
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The code to get Picklist values looks alright. Does the visualforce page have a repeat over the collection of SelectOptions ? Could you post the entire VF page with markup?

Comment: What are you getting instead of CSV output? I would expect that, for one thing, it's all on one line, since there are no newlines.

Comment: You really need to list a) what you've tried and b) what the error is. Right now this question is likely to be closed without more information.

Comment: I need a simple extract of picklist values for all the picklist fields present in all the objects from my org.

Comment: If the title of your question is your question, you should also use the `code` highlight -- also you shouldn't post edits in answers to the questions.

Comment: In your second `<apex:repeat>`, shouldn't it be "{!a2}", rather than "{!a1}"?

Comment: why are the repeats nested ?

Answer (score 4):

Your code that builds the list of selectOptions is fine, but never gets called, your VF page accesses `sOptions`, but nothing has set that until `getSpecialitiesForSection`() has run, change your apex code to

```
public class  getSpecialitiesForSelection {

    public list<SelectOption> getsOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> sOptions = new List<SelectOption> ();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Industry;
        for(Schema.PickListEntry p : f.getPicklistValues()) {
            sOptions.add(new SelectOption(p.getValue(), p.getLabel()));
        }
        return sOptions;
    }
}
```